# How do I modify this program so that instead having a block of array elements, i use a for-loop to initialize the array values?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

the first block of `anArray[] = n;` is what needs to be modified as a `for-loop`. I don't know how to change all of the values into a `for-loop`.

```
public class ArrayDemo
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        int [] anArray;      // declares an array of integers

        anArray = new int[10];  // allocates memory for 10 integers

        anArray[0] = 100;  // initializes first element
        anArray[1] = 200;  // initializes second element
        anArray[2] = 300;  // etc.
        anArray[3] = 400;
        anArray[4] = 500;
        anArray[5] = 600;
        anArray[6] = 700;
        anArray[7] = 800;
        anArray[8] = 900;
        anArray[9] = 1000;

        for (int i = 0; i < anArray.length; i++)
        System.out.println("Element at index " + i + ": " + anArray[i]);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < anArray.length; i++)
    anArray[i] = i * 100 + 100;      // Assume start with 100
```

Just using for loop like what you did for print out